My Brute Force is Not Working in Python 3
I have a Hash Cracker tool that i made it myself using python 3.12. Here is the code:
r"""
 _   _           _           ____                             _             
| | | | __ _ ___| |__       |  _ \  ___  ___ _ __ _   _ _ __ | |_ ___  _ __ 
| |_| |/ _` / __| '_ \ _____| | | |/ _ \/ __| '__| | | | '_ \| __/ _ \| '__|
|  _  | (_| \__ \ | | |_____| |_| |  __/ (__| |  | |_| | |_) | || (_) | |   
|_| |_|\__,_|___/_| |_|     |____/ \___|\___|_|   \__, | .__/ \__\___/|_|   
                                                  |___/|_|

[*] Author : Mowland Production
[*] Github : https://github.com/cyberpnx05
[*] Version : 1.0

Warning! This program is for educational purpose only...!

"""

import argparse
import hashlib
import itertools
import os.path
import string
import sys as _sys
import textwrap
import time


salt = string.ascii_letters+string.digits


# Hash definition
SHA256 = hashlib.sha256()
MD5 = hashlib.md5()
SHA1 = hashlib.sha1()

# Coloring
ERROR = "\x1b[31;1m"
WARNING = "\x1b[33;1m"
SUCCESS = "\x1b[32;1m"
INFO = "\x1b[34;1m"
NORMAL = "\x1b[0m"

def sha256_decrypt(hash_strings:str, wordfile:str):
    print(f"{WARNING}[*] Initializing....{NORMAL}\n")
    time.sleep(2)

    if args.decrypt_mode == "brute":
        for i in range(1, 20):
            for x in itertools.product(salt, repeat=i):
                word = "".join(x).rstrip()
                SHA256.update(word.encode())
                if hash_strings == SHA256.hexdigest():
                    print(f"{SUCCESS}[*]{NORMAL} {hash_strings} is Decrypted...")
                    print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Decrypted string is ==> {INFO}{word}{NORMAL}")

                else:
                    print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Attempting to decrypt {INFO}{hash_strings}{NORMAL} with --> {INFO}{SHA256.hexdigest()}{NORMAL} --> {word}")

    else:
        try:
            with open(wordfile, "r") as wordlist:
                for word in wordlist.readlines():
                    SHA256.update(word.rstrip("\n").encode())
                    if hash_strings == SHA256.hexdigest():
                        print(f"{SUCCESS}[*]{NORMAL} {hash_strings} is Decrypted...")
                        print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Decrypted string is ==> {INFO}{word.rstrip("\n")}{NORMAL}")

                    else:
                        print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Attempting to decrypt {INFO}{hash_strings}{NORMAL} with --> {INFO}{SHA256.hexdigest()}{NORMAL} --> {word.rstrip("\n")}")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"{ERROR}[*]{NORMAL} The specified path is not found...!")

def sha1_decrypt(hash_strings:str, wordfile:str):
    print(f"{WARNING}[*] Initializing....{NORMAL}\n")
    time.sleep(3)

    if args.decrypt_mode == "brute":
        for i in range(1, 20):
            for x in itertools.product(salt, repeat=i):
                SHA1.update(("".join(x)).encode())
                if hash_strings == SHA1.hexdigest():
                    print(f"{SUCCESS}[*]{NORMAL} {hash_strings} is Decrypted...")
                    print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Decrypted string is ==> {INFO}{"".join(x)}{NORMAL}")

                else:
                    print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Attempting to decrypt hash with string --> {INFO}{"".join(x)}{NORMAL}")

    else:
        try:
            with open(wordfile, "r") as wordlist:
                for word in wordlist.readline().strip("\n"):
                    SHA1.update(word.encode())
                    if hash_strings == SHA1.hexdigest():
                        print(f"{SUCCESS}[*]{NORMAL} {hash_strings} is Decrypted...")
                        print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Decrypted string is ==> {INFO}{word}{NORMAL}")

                    else:
                        print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Attempting to decrypt hash with string --> {INFO}{word}{NORMAL}")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"{ERROR}[*]{NORMAL} The specified path is not found...!")

def md5_decrypt(hash_strings:str, wordfile:str):
    print(f"{WARNING}[*] Initializing....{NORMAL}\n")
    time.sleep(3)

    if args.decrypt_mode == "brute":
        for i in range(1, 20):
            for x in itertools.product(salt, repeat=i):
                MD5.update(("".join(x)).encode())
                if hash_strings ==  MD5.hexdigest():
                    print(f"{SUCCESS}[*]{NORMAL} {hash_strings} is Decrypted...")
                    print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Decrypted string is ==> {INFO}{"".join(x)}{NORMAL}")

                else:
                    print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Attempting to decrypt hash with string --> {INFO}{"".join(x)}{NORMAL}")

    else:
        try:
            with open(wordfile, "r") as wordlist:
                for word in wordlist.readline().strip("\n"):
                    MD5.update(word.encode())
                    if hash_strings ==  MD5.hexdigest():
                        print(f"{SUCCESS}[*]{NORMAL} {hash_strings} is Decrypted...")
                        print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Decrypted string is ==> {INFO}{word}{NORMAL}")

                    else:
                        print(f"{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Attempting to decrypt hash with string --> {INFO}{word}{NORMAL}")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"{ERROR}[*]{NORMAL} The specified path is not found...!")


            



def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=os.path.basename(__file__), formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, description=textwrap.dedent(fr"""
{INFO} _   _           _           ____                             _             
| | | | __ _ ___| |__       |  _ \  ___  ___ _ __ _   _ _ __ | |_ ___  _ __ 
| |_| |/ _` / __| '_ \ _____| | | |/ _ \/ __| '__| | | | '_ \| __/ _ \| '__|
|  _  | (_| \__ \ | | |_____| |_| |  __/ (__| |  | |_| | |_) | || (_) | |   
|_| |_|\__,_|___/_| |_|     |____/ \___|\___|_|   \__, | .__/ \__\___/|_|   
                                                  |___/|_|{NORMAL}

{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Author : Mowland Production
{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Github : https://github.com/XHadow_21
{INFO}[*]{NORMAL} Version : 1.0

{WARNING}Warning! This program is for educational purpose only...!{NORMAL}
"""))
    parser.add_argument("-ht", "--hash-type", required=True, choices=["sha256", "sha1", "md5"], dest="hash_type", type=str, help="Define Hash type to decrypt")
    parser.add_argument("-hv", "--hash-value", required=True, dest="hash_string", type=str, help="Hash string to decrypt")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--mode", choices=["brute", "wordlist"], dest="decrypt_mode", help="Method to decrypt the hash", default="brute")
    parser.add_argument("-w", "--wordlist", dest="wordlist", help="Wordlist file", metavar="FILE", default=None)

    global args

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if (args.decrypt_mode == "wordlist") and (args.wordlist == "" or args.wordlist == None):
        parser.print_help()
        exit(1)

    match(args.hash_type, args.decrypt_mode):
        case("sha256", "brute"):
            sha256_decrypt(args.hash_string, "None")

        case("sha256", "wordlist"):
            sha256_decrypt(args.hash_string, args.wordlist)

        case("sha1", "brute"):
            sha1_decrypt(args.hash_string, "None")

        case("sha1", "wordlist"):
            sha1_decrypt(args.hash_string, args.wordlist)

        case("md5", "brute"):
            md5_decrypt(args.hash_string, "None")

        case("md5", "wordlist"):
            md5_decrypt(args.hash_string, args.wordlist)

        case _:
            parser.print_help()
            exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


After I created this code, I generate a SHA256 hash using python hashlib in my Windows Terminal
import hashlib

sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update("123".encode())
sha256.hexdigest()

and it generates this Hash Value a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3.
Meanwhile, in my tools above it generates the same text value which is 123 with a completely different hash which is 5c8b2454d77163fa3f498410f02f90b2bbc43504b45981cf125986c060a70481
compared with the hash i generated before in my Windows Terminal. How could this possible...?
I expect that it would be the same with the hash I generated before in my Windows Terminal

You're reusing the same hash object hashlib.sha256() for different inputs. Calling SHA256.update() for different inputs is equivalent to concatenating all of them, so you will NOT get the hash of each input word, but only a final hash for all of them concatenated.
You SHOULD create a new hash object for each input you want to test. For example:
import hashlib

SHA256 = hashlib.sha256()
SHA256.update("123".encode())
print(SHA256.hexdigest())
# a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3

SHA256.update("123".encode())
print(SHA256.hexdigest())
# 96cae35ce8a9b0244178bf28e4966c2ce1b8385723a96a6b838858cdd6ca0a1e

SHA256 = hashlib.sha256()
SHA256.update("123123".encode())
print(SHA256.hexdigest())
# 96cae35ce8a9b0244178bf28e4966c2ce1b8385723a96a6b838858cdd6ca0a1e

